# python traceback exception global name not defined

Tags: python

I have the below code that writes a file and prints any exception.

Currently, i get a exception as the folder is not available(thats valid) but I get a

```
error

 "global name 'exc_info' is not defined"...
```

Code

```
try:
     with open(tmp_file_upload + uploadfile.raw_filename,'w') as open_file:
         open_file.write(uploadfile.file.read())
except Exception,err:
      import traceback
      exc_info = sys.exc_info()
      traceback.print_exception(*exc_info)
      print "File write failed"
```

Full trace:

```
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]   File "/web/docs/bottle.py", line 861, in _handle
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]     return route.call(**args)
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]   File "/web/docs/bottle.py", line 1725, in wrapper
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]     rv = callback(*a, **ka)
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]   File "/web/docs/GUI/PBottleApp.py", line 293, in datasets
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81]     exc_info = sys.exc_info()
[Wed Mar 18 16:28:48 2015] [error] [client 10.172.16.81] NameError: global name 'exc_info' is not defined
```

Comment: That traceback doesn't seem to match the behaviour - `exc_info` doesn't need to be defined to be assigned to, and if `sys.exc_info` was missing you'd get an `AttributeError` instead.

Comment: Wild guess: you saved this version of the code *after* the program was already running - so that the code on disk (as shown in the traceback) doesn't match the code that's actually running.  Which is probably something like `exc_info = exc_info()`, which would actually produce the shown error.

Comment: Because the error and your source clearly don’t match (no global exc_info name in sight) the only way you’d get this error is if you edited the source code but didn’t restart the script.

Answer (score -1):

This is a library import error. Please import the correct library as follows.

```
import traceback
```

Comment: If you read the question and the comments carefully, I am quite sure this is not the problem.

Comment: For someone who has Googled for "nameerror: global name 'traceback' is not defined", this might be the fix you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    with open(tmp_file_upload + uploadfile.raw_filename,'w') as open_file:
         open_file.write(uploadfile.file.read())
except Exception,err:
    e_info = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_exception(*e_info)
    print "File write failed"
```

can you try this code like this?